# daemon: fatal: failed to tell if .... is safe

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I'm trying to run a process as a daemon and write it's PID in pidfile.
But when I run it it gives me an error:

```
daemon: fatal: failed to tell if /home/ubuntu/storm/storm-0.8.2/bin/storm supervisor > /dev/null && echo $! > /var/run/supervisor-storm.pid is safe: No such file or directory
```

here is the code:

```
PID_FILE=/var/run/supervisor-storm.pid
STORM_BIN=/home/ubuntu/storm/storm-0.8.2/bin/

 start() {
     echo "Starting storm supervisor..."
     STORM_PROCESS="$STORM_BIN/storm supervisor &"
     daemon "$STORM_PROCESS > /dev/null && echo \$! > $PID_FILE"
 }
```

However If I copy this output command after `daemon:fatal: failed to tell if ....` and run it in terminal everything works great: it runs on the background, creates a pidfile.

Please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just stick em in a $()

```
    echo "Starting storm supervisor..."
    STORM_PROCESS= $($STORM_BIN/storm supervisor &)
    $(daemon $STORM_PROCESS > /dev/null && echo \$! > $PID_FILE)
```

But really, don't bother using daemon. Your process is in the background and running. Just work with it as it is. You've got a pid file, that's enough.

Comment: @Uberdoyle Why shouldn't you bother using daemon (or in my case start-stop-daemon) ????

Comment: Just build it yourself. Here's a simple one you can use. https://github.com/UberDoyle/evil-kittens/tree/master/test_service

Answer (score 0):

This error also comes when your executable does not exist on the given system.

Plus as the suggestion in the other answer, prefer not to use `daemon`. Rather simply write `init.d` (or equivalent) scripts to get your work done.